# Javascript popup don't created as expected for Windows 7 + IE8

Tags: javascript, windows-7, internet-explorer-8, window.open

Javascript popup don't created as expected. The problem is with height of the window, To open a javascript window, we are using window.open() function with screen.availHeight. Popup created is too long in the height and goes down to the windows taskbar. Same code is working with other windows platforms and the bottom of popup is just touching windows taskbar and not going beyond it.

Environment with problem - Windows 7 + IE8

After lots of investigations we found that the screen.availHeight is not returned properly and it is 122px more than the actual value. We found another method to get the correct of availHeight at http://w3schools.invisionzone.com/index.php?showtopic=28247. When we supplied the same height to window.open(), the newly created popup is little less in height, though it should touch the windows taskbar. It seems that there is something wrong with the JavaScript api’s and it don't respect windows current resolution properly.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `window.innerHeight` or `window.outerHeight` would work better.
`document.documentElement.offsetHeight` usually works too